# Jquery elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a small project and I've ran in to a problem.
I'm using jQuery to create new elements. So because they were not in the document when the page loaded, I can't manipulate them in any way.
Is there a way to make jQuery read the new elements in order to fix my problem?

```
$("img.fbimg").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use event delegation:

```
$("body").on("click", "img.fbimg", function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Here you may replace `"body"` with any *static* parent element of `img.fbimg`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to need

```
$(document.body).on('click', "img.fbimg", function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

This would let the `click` event be catched even on dynamically added elements whose selector is `"img.fbimg"`.

Note that if you have a more precise element containing your images and existing on load, it would be more efficient to use

```
$('#idOfElementContainingAllTheImages').on('click', "img.fbimg", function(){
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/)